# can I iterate through files using google apps script using an iteration order other than latest modified time

Tags: google-apps-script, iteration

I am iterating through text files using Google Apps Script and the pasting contents of text files to a google sheet

```
var allFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles()
var file = allFiles.next()
var fileContent = file.getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString()
sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
var pasteRange = sheet.getRange(rowId,205)
pasteRange.setValues(fileContent)
```

All is fine. The variable RowId is taken from the filename of the text file.  The problem is that a user may create a text file for RowId 230 then 1 minute later another user may also create row 230.  I need the latter user to take priority.  But Google iterates through the files using most recent first leaving me with the oldest update to row 230 in the google sheet.

Is there any way of sorting the files in the file iterator to determine the iteration order. I can manipulate the filename if that helps.

thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question.  Would you like to immediately update the individual row that was edited? If your row id is linked to the file name, then how about reversing the order of operations and getting that file from Drive, based on the row that was edited, instead of getting all files at once?

Comment: Basically I have multiple text files.  Often 2 or more of these text files refer to the same row in a Google Sheet.  If one was created at 11:13 am  and second was created 11:30am then the file iterator looks at the 11:30am one first and amends the corresponding google sheet row that is found in the file name.  Then it iterates to the second file from 11:13am and amends the same Google sheet row.  But I need it to iterate the other way around i.e do the earlier file first then end with the latest.

Comment: I've come up with one solution...  I put the time it was created into the filename then iterate through the files and get the filenames into an array then I can sort that array, then getFileByName for each array element.

Comment: That's a good idea. You can pass a comparator function to array.sort() method to parse the file name and sort them by any condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using GSuite API Services (`DriveApp`), its not possible. However there is an advanced set of services referenced [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). These are wrappers for the respective REST APIS for Drive, Sheets and other Google REST-based services.To use them you'll need to enable the service as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

Once you have the Drive service enabled, you'll have to navigate the [REST API documentation for Drive V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) to figure out the methods you need to use (though Apps Script has an auto-complete feature that will aid you). For example, to list files, you can reference the Advanced Service from the `Drive` (**NOT** `DriveApp`)module as follows:

```
Drive.Files.list(options);
```

`options` is an object with parameters listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list). The `orderBy` option should have what you need to sort the files.

Comment: Ahh nice.  I forgot to look at the advanced services options.  I've used Drive so yes this will do it and it's cleaner than my 2 step approach  thanks